# django ManyToManyField show slug as label

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

i have a "rare" behavior here, i this model:

## models.py

```
class Area(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.date.today,editable=False)
    activa = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Empresa(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)       
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    actividad = models.ManyToManyField(Area)
```

I dont know why the m2m_field actividad, into the django admin and any forms html is showing the slug field from the model Area as label

[image]

Comment: Do you have `__unicode__` method defined on your models?

Comment: Thanks for asking me that... i was just returning the slug field and not the name.

Answer (score 0):

i was just returning the slug field and not the area "name"

```
class Area(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.date.today,editable=False)
    activa = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.area  # was self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/areas/%s' % self.slug
```